# Can I upgrade my htc to a newer version os?

Tags: updates

Can someone please give me some advice on upgrading my htc to kitkat or help me find out what my device is comparable with to instal or can I instal anything I want which I don't think so bc the ram size has to do with what my phone can properly run??? Right?? Idk what I know about android I've learned trial and error and reading online. Some educatated advice would be greatly appreciated thanks

Android version 2.3.5
HTC sense version 3.0
ROM VERSION 3.12.405.1
Software number LeeDrOiD_HD_V5.1.1_GB
BUILD 3.12.405,1 CL199157 release keys

Comment: Please check the link : https://forum.xda-developers.com/htc-sensation. You can search for your exact model on top-right option to search devices

Comment: For further hints, you can also consult our [updates tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/updates/info).

Comment: Ok so I should've been more descriptive I think. My phone is rooted what I'm trying to do is install the latest firmware software and/or custom rom. It's my wifi phone with no paid service. One of the problems I'm trying to resolve is not being able to install new apps. I download an APK  some install and others say parse error when I try to install.

Comment: Izzy already provided the go-to-source for those. Officially you can have Android 4.0 with Sense 3.6, but unofficial ones goes to (beyond?) Sense 5, and even further without Sense.

Comment: Above and beyond yes that's where I'm trying to get to. I'm new here and not sure if there's kinda certain things that we can't say or whatever but yea I wanna make this phone perform to the highest ability....I'm just not exactly sure how to do so. I know what to do but I don't know exactly HOW to do so. I've got several root apps that I've been digging around in and then there's those couple of dusty androids that I fckd up bc I thought I knew what I was doing but only ended up with a locked up phone.